# RealityKit – Text mesh resource performance warning

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have an object in `RealityKit` that I hover some text over. I make the text using the built in static function on `MeshResource` like this.

```swift
let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText("Some text", extrusionDepth: 0.01, font: MeshResource.Font.systemFont(ofSize: 0.05), containerFrame: .zero, alignment: .center, lineBreakMode: .byTruncatingTail)
let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .green, isMetallic: false)
let textEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: textMesh, materials: [material])
```

The text shows up but I get warnings from `ARKit` (`RealityKit`) about using a wrong font type and something about performance? These logs fill up my terminal because I actually update the text in the `ARView` regularly. This is how I update the text.

```swift
let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText("Some new text", extrusionDepth: 0.01, font: MeshResource.Font.systemFont(ofSize: 0.05), containerFrame: .zero, alignment: .center, lineBreakMode: .byTruncatingTail)
//textEntity variable gets stored in my app so I can keep track of it / them out side ARView
textEntity?.model?.mesh = textMesh
```

Here is the warning. I get hundreds of them but I'll only burden you with one.

```sh
CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "System Font Regular" and got font with PostScript name ".SFUI-Regular". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
```

I would prefer to resolve this warning but if I can't and it's just something I have to live with until Apple iterates this framework can I at least silence it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

You can try ***Helvetica*** font. But there's no 100% guarantee that it'll fix the issue in any Xcode version.

```
let textEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateText("RealityKit", 
                             font: .init(name: "Helvetica", size: 0.5)!))
```

But 99% of the time it worked.

### About warnings

Console warnings come from RealityKit `.cpp` files. To silence them, go to Xcode menu `Product` –> `Scheme` –> `Edit Scheme` and add to environment dictionary `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` key with its corresponding `disable` value.

```
OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
```

At the moment, it's the most efficient way to disable RealityKit 2.0 warnings.

You can check this in ViewController with:

```
print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OS_ACTIVITY_MODE"])

// Result:  disable
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! This worked, "Helvetica" solved the issue. If you end up wanting that consulting work let me know on LinkedIn!

Comment: I'll definitely not need consulting work in the next 2 years, but thanks for the offer, Jon!

Comment: Although it’s a sans-serif typeface too, Helvetica isn’t the same as `.systemFont`. The current system font on iOS and macOS is called [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/). Using `.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)` is recommended and does not throw any errors as of August 2023.